# Adding a leading zero to the integer part of a string when it is a single digit only?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a more concise way to achieve the following...

I have a df (>1M rows) with a column in the following example format:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["ea11", "ea1", "ea3io10d"]})`

My wish is to add a leading 0 only to each single digit found in the string.

So the transformed column I would like to output is:

`["ea11", "ea01", "ea03io10d"]`

I have found a workable but inefficient and super ugly solution.

`df["col"] = df["col"].str.split(r"(\d+)", regex=True).apply(lambda x: list(filter(None, x))).apply(lambda x:  "".join(list(map(myfunc, x))))`

I didn't find a question of this specific type previously asked so any help with a more efficient solution would be greatly appreciated :) Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code. Hope it will work for you too.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["ea11", "ea1", "ea3io10d"]})
def add_leading_zero(match):
    return match.group(1) + match.group(2).zfill(2)

df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace(r'(\D)(\d)(?!\d)', add_leading_zero, regex=True)
print(df)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Much more efficient and readable. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex and lookarounds:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)', r'0\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
        col        new
0      ea11       ea11
1       ea1       ea01
2  ea3io10d  ea03io10d
3         1         01
```

###### regex

```
(?<!\d)  # match must not be preceded by a number
(\d)     # capture single digit
(?!\d)   # match must not be followed by a number

0\1      # replace by "0" and captured number
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L2sN2A/1)

Alternatively, for a generic solution to have a minimal number of digits, capture all numbers and use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
N = 2
df['new'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\d+', lambda m: m.group().zfill(N),
                                  regex=True)
```